# Submit the form without loading div

Tags: javascript, php

I am struggling to enter the form if the the div is not loaded, What I am trying is if the option "Grade B or Less" is selected then form should be able to submit and if "Grade A" is selected then next div to be loaded and then form to be submitted,

Here is my php form

```
<div class="box box-primary">
      <?php if (isset($_POST['status'])) { ?>
        <div id="file_updated_box">
          <div class="alert alert-info alert-dismissible file_updated">
            <button aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="alert" class="close" type="button">×</button>
            <h4><i class="icon fa fa-check"></i><?php echo $_POST['status']; ?></h4>
          </div>
        </div>
      <?php } ?>
      <div class="box-header with-border">
        <h3 class="box-title">Enter IMEI</h3>
      </div>
      <!-- /.box-header -->
      <!-- form start -->
      <form method="post" action="sonim_harvesting.php">
        <div class="box-body">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
              <label for="imeinum">Job IMEI</label>
              <input class="form-control" autofocus autocomplete="off" id="imeinum" name="imeinum" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['imeinum'])) {
                                                                                                            echo $_POST['imeinum'];
                                                                                                          } ?>" name="imeinum" placeholder="Enter IMEI" type="text">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Device Power ON:</label>
            <div>
              <div class="radio">
                <label>
                  <input name="device_power" value="YES" type="radio" class="radio" required>
                  YES
                </label>
              </div>
              <div class="radio">
                <label>
                  <input name="device_power" value="NO" required type="radio" class="radio">
                  NO
                </label>
              </div>


            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group grade">
            <label class="control-label">Device Grade:</label>
            <div>
              <div class="radio">
                <label>
                  <input name="device_grade" id="GradeA" value="A" type="radio" class="radio" required>
                  Grade A
                </label>
              </div>
              <div class="radio">
                <label>
                  <input name="device_grade" value="B or Less" required type="radio" class="radio">
                  Grade B or Less
                </label>
              </div>


            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group function" style="display:none">
            <label class="control-label">Is Display Functional? :</label>
            <div>
              <div class="radio">
                <label>
                  <input name="function" value="YES" type="radio" class="radio" required>
                  YES
                </label>
              </div>
              <div class="radio">
                <label>
                  <input name="function" value="NO" required type="radio" class="radio">
                  NO
                </label>
              </div>


            </div>
          </div>
        </div>


        <!-- /.box-body -->
        <div class="box-footer">
          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="jbSubmit" value="Submit" />
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
```

and here is my js code

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $('.grade').hide()
  $('.function').hide()

  $('input[type="radio"]').click(function() {
    $('.grade').show();
  });
  $('.grade').click(function() {
    if ($('#GradeA').is(":checked")) {
      $('.function').show()
    } else {

    }
  })



});
```

I am able to do it with Grade A but If Grade B is selected I am not able to submit the form, Please advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your radio input with `name="function"` has the `required` attribute set. Despite not being visible, the form is still expecting this field to be completed.

The simplest solution here would be to either remove the `required` attribute or consider setting one of the options as `checked` by default.